# Как подсчитать количество повторений каждого из значений массива?

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив:

```
Array (
  [0] => 1
  [1] => 1
  [2] => 1
  [3] => 2
)
```

Пример: в сессиях я храню `ID` товара, количество добавленных товаров с `ID = 1` три, как видно в массиве выше.

Как получить данное количество в переменную, зная `ID` товара?

Answer (score 8):

Например

```
$array = array('1','1','1','2');
$result = array_count_values($array);
```

получаем

```
Array (
  [1] => 3
  [2] => 1
)
```

Тоесть чтобы узнать количество вхождений ключа `1`

```
echo $result[1];
```

Answer (score 4):

Чтобы посчитать только по одному ID, можно так:

```
$data = [1,1,1,3];
$ID = 1;
$n = array_reduce( $data, function($p, $c){ return $p + ($c == $ID ? 1 : 0);}, 0);
```

Встроенная в PHP функция [`array_reduce()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-reduce.php) позволяет получить из массива всего одно значение, пройдясь по всем элементам – как раз наш случай.

Answer (score 1):

Может так? Или задача более специфична?

```
$arr = array(1, 1, 1, 2);
$num = 0;
$id = 1;
foreach ($arr as &$value) {
    If ($value == $id) {
        $num++;
    }
}
...
unset($value);
```

Comment: Чем ссылка на значение предпочтительнее просто переменной в данном случае?

Comment: Согласен, без ссылки и ансета. Преимуществ она не даёт.

Answer (score 0):

Я конечно, поздновато буду, но решение для тех кто по каким-то причинам не может использовать array_count_values:

```
$arr = array(1, 1, 1, 2);
$count = [];
foreach($arr as $ar) {
   if (!isset($count[$ar])) {
      $count[$ar] = 0;
   }
   $count[$ar]++;
}
print_r($count);
```